# Select data with latest date for each id

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I am currently working on Microsoft Access an I am struggling to do what I want.
I have this table A:

```
Table A

id    title  name   date
123   azer   dfgd   1
123   afg    qsd    5
123   arr    poi    7
123   aur    qhg    3
456   aoe    aer    3
456   iuy    zer    4
```

And I would like to get the columns id,title and  name that have the latest date (highest number) for each id

With that example, the query would give

```
id  title name date
123  arr  poi   7
456  iuy  zer   4
```

I hope you'll be able to help me.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.date = (select max(a2.date) from a as a2 where a2.id = a.id);
```

For performance, you want an index on `a(id, date)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it gives the good result.
But I have another question, I use this query on a table with 300K rows, and I need to export the results in a table or an excel file. However, when I try to do so, the computer has a really hard time because the table is so large. Do you have any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and date > t.date
)
```